# how to use spring boot for websocket reverse proxy

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-ws, netflix-zuul

I am using [web-proxy](https://github.com/barrett-rob/java-websocket-reverse-proxy/tree/master/src/main/java/com/jwrp/javawebsocketreverseproxy) code to have reverse websocket proxy using spring-boot, it works during initial connection after that I get this below error

```
java.lang.illegalstateexception: the remote endpoint was in state [text_partial_writing] which is an invalid state for called method  , I tried with adding synchronized block but seemed as difficult to make it stable.
```

I tried to use spring-cloud-gateway but it is not compatible with spring-starter-web(I can not remove web due to spring MVC dependency in the code)

Is it possible to achieve web-socket proxy using zuul or is there a way to router websocket request if it on specific URL?

Comment: Any luck on this ?

Comment: no, I moved to spring cloud gateway